# Functions in a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a dll with some functions.
Header exemple:

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool Test()
```

;
And i have another simple application to use that function:

```
typedef bool(CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)();

HINSTANCE hDLL;               // Handle to DLL
LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc1;    // Function pointer
bool uReturnVal;

hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"NAME.dll");
if (hDLL != NULL)
{
    lpfnDllFunc1 = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"Test");
    if (!lpfnDllFunc1)
    {
        // handle the error
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        cout << "error";
    }
    else
    {
        // call the function
        uReturnVal = lpfnDllFunc1();
    }
}
```

But don't work. The function isn't found.

Comment: what does it mean? is dll loaded and function found? is lpfnDllFunc1 not null?

Comment: Posting some of your output would be helpful here... we have no clue if your DLL was even found or if there's another issue with attempting to load it.

Comment: The dll is loaded but the function isn't found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic senses tell me that the function wasn't found because you forgot to declare it as `extern "C"`.

Because of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) in C++, the actual function name that gets put into the DLL's export table is a longer, more gibberish-y string than just `Test` if the function has C++ linkage.  If you instead declare it with C linkage, then it will be exported with the expected name and can therefore be imported more easily.

For example:

```
// Header file
#ifdef __cplusplus
// Declare all following functions with C linkage
extern "C"
{
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) bool Test();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
// End C linkage
#endif

// DLL source file
extern "C"
{

__declspec(dllexport) bool Test()
{
    // Function body
    ...
}

}  // End C linkage
```